# How can I get an estimate of the time remaining until the code has finished running?

Tags: python, time

I have some test code here:

```py
# Print iterations progress
from random import randint, uniform
from time import sleep, time
import os

mem_bytes = os.sysconf('SC_PAGE_SIZE') * os.sysconf('SC_PHYS_PAGES')
mem_gib = mem_bytes/(1024.**3)

howManyToCompile = randint(100, 1000000)


def printProgress(current, total, remaining, decimals="2", prefix="Compiling shaders", suffix="Complete", printEnd="\r"):
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (current / float(total)))
    print(f'\r{prefix}: {current} / {total} {str.lower(suffix)} ({percent}% - {remaining}s left) ', end = printEnd)
    if current == total: 
        print()

printProgress(0, howManyToCompile, (0))
for i in range(howManyToCompile):
    t1 = time()

    sleep(uniform(0.05, 0.1 * mem_gib))

    t2 = time()
    printProgress(i + 1, howManyToCompile, (t2-t1))
```

But when I run it, I get something like this:

`Compiling shaders: 47 / [random amount] complete (0.01% - 0.15282988548278809s left)`

But the issue is that it's getting the time until that one "shader" is finished "compiling", not the average time remaining until the loop itself ends.

How can I make it estimate the time left until the loop ends?

Comment: Put `t1 = time()` *before* the loop so you'll have a timing from the start until the current point.

Comment: It'd start counting up if I did that.

Comment: have you tried `tqdm` [link](https://tqdm.github.io/)?

Comment: Submit that as a solution and I'll accept it @vyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write debug output to the screen at the same time or want multiple colors, I would look at [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/). Lots of options for customization and examples in the [docs](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

```python
import enlighten

manager = enlighten.get_manager()
pbar = manager.counter(total=howManyToCompile, color='red')

for i in pbar(range(howManyToCompile)):
    sleep(0.01)
    print(i)
```

tqdm can handle printing, but it requires extra steps and can easily become overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

[**tqdm**](https://tqdm.github.io/) is a python utility that serves as a progress indicator. Usage is very straightforward:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    ...
```

More information and advanced usage can be seen in the [documentation](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/).